# How to keep the dimensions when using the basic arithmetic operations with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I encounter a dimension problem and has to reshape the array after each calculation. For example,

```
a=np.random.rand(2,3,4)
t=2
b=a[:,1,:] + a[:,2,:]*t
```

The second axis of `a` is reduced automatically and `b` becomes a 2x4 array. How to keep the shape of `b` to be [2,1,4]. In `numpy.sum()`, we can set `keepdims=True`, but for the basic arithmetic operations, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the integer indies into lists:

```
>>> b = a[:,[1],:] + a[:,[2],:]*t
>>> b.shape
(2, 1, 4)
```